# How to Integrate React Epub Reader with next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to integrate [react epub reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-reader)  with Next Js  but getting one error and  works  well with react js,  **I need your help to integrate epub reader with next js**

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5CQ7.png)

My code

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactReader } from "react-reader";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
         <div style={{ position: "relative", height: "330px" }}>
<ReactReader
        url="./Boy without a name English.epub"
        title={"Alice in wonderland"}
        location={"epubcfi(/6/2[cover]!/6)"}
        locationChanged={epubcifi => console.log(epubcifi)}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js SyntaxError "Unexpected token 'export'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936222/next-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export)

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be fixed by transpiling `react-reader` and `epubjs` modules (exported as ESM since a few months back).

For example, using `next-transpile-modules` in Next.js config:

```js
// next.config.js
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["react-reader", "epubjs"]);

module.exports = withTM({/* custom config */});
```